# How can I add hover in my dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, hover

I tried inserting `&:hover` into my code but nothing works. This is my code. How can I add hover effects with this code? I guess there's some problem with my scss code but I cannot figure it out.

```js
$(".dropdown").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('is-active');
});
```

```css
.arrow-toggle {
  &:before, &:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 10px 0;
    right: 5px;
  }
  &:before {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    // 50% - half of arrow size - arrow thickness
    top: calc(50% - 7px);
    border-color: blue transparent transparent;
  }
  &:after {
    border-color: yellow transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 5px);
  }
}

.dropdown {
  width: 200px;
   height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  @extend .arrow-toggle;
  
  &.is-active {
    transform: scaleY(-1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown"></div>
```

Comment: this is SCSS code, it will never work directly in an HTML page...(translate it in CSS) and your dropdown is empty

Comment: You can either see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65094527/14631135) or you can check out this [codepen](https://codepen.io/dasshounak/pen/KKgzwWz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install scss compiler in vscode and first compile the scss to normal css, add the css file to your html.

```
&:hover {
        color:yellow;
    }
```

this snippet should work.

Answer (score 0):

try using :hover pseudo class. You can also checkout [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp)